# Take an EF 6 Migration down via code (not from package manager console)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

On an administration page for a portal, we have a button that will migrate the database to the latest version after a code deployment. This is done with the SetInitializer (see below)

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MigrationContext, Configuration>());
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
dbMigrator.Update();
```

For testing purposes, we would like to add another button to *down* the migration back to the start. In Package Manager Console, this can be with `update-database -target 0`.

We are using Entity Framework 6, .NET 4.5.1

Does anyone know of a way to make this happen via code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does `dbMigrator.Update("PreviousMigrationName"); // Untested` work?

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829363(v=vs.113).aspx, *targetMigration* is "The migration to upgrade/downgrade to."

If you want to go down to the first migration, I would think `dbMigrator.Update("FirstMigrationName");` would do the trick.